# Blender 2.8 - How to create new view ports / windows?

Tags: 3d-view

In blender 2.7 you could easily create new windows and configure your workspace as you wished, by draggin the symbols seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

How does it work in blender 2.8? Was this great feature removed??

Comment: It's still the same. Click in the corners of the areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still works the way it always did. But for some reason, the "triangle in the corner" icon has been removed. If you hover your mouse cursor over the corner of a window, you will see it change from a pointer to a kind of plus sign. When this change happens, clicking and dragging will create your new window in the expected way.